# Accessing huge 3D array in a file with ff package

Tags: r

For example, 15 GB 3D cube of 32f type is stored in a file in binary format. I know ff package let user map an object to a memory-mapped file. So I wonder if, with ff, I can map an object to the 3D cube file that was not created by ff.

Apparent benefit would be efficient memory management while using the 3D cube. I tried to find some references on this but I couldn't find any related material even from ff package documentation. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, though I have not tried this before.

Simple test:

```
library(ff)
writeBin(as.vector(volcano), "file.bin", size = 8)
a <- ff(filename = "file.bin", readonly = TRUE, vmode = "double", dim = dim(volcano))
image(as.ram(a))
```

I would test carefully before you work with that file of yours, but that works with readonly = FALSE and I can modify values, delete a, recreate it and the modifications are there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is great news for me as I can preprocess and analyze the cube without leaving R.